# Sending message to a Handler on a dead thread when using Facebook GraphRequest in IntentService

Tags: java, android, multithreading, facebook, android-asynctask

I'm calling a Facebook GraphRequest (....) from within an IntentService, and I end up with the following error:

**Logcat:**

> W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {15237a6e} sending
>   message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler)
>   {15237a6e} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                                                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
>                                                                                   at com.facebook.GraphRequest.runCallbacks(GraphRequest.java:1395)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeConnectionAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1279)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1164)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequestBatch.executeAndWaitImpl(GraphRequestBatch.java:252)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequestBatch.executeAndWait(GraphRequestBatch.java:201)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(GraphRequestAsyncTask.java:169)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.facebook.GraphRequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(GraphRequestAsyncTask.java:37)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

What is the reason of the error and how to fix it?